# How do I store dates in an array in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I'm making a basic planner style app which takes a date input from the user and then represents it in a table. I have created my data model and I am trying to add some sample data to test the model.

This is my data model:

```
import UIKit

class Data {
    var name: String
    var time1: NSDate
    var time2: NSDate
    var time3: NSDate
    var time4: NSDate
    var time5: NSDate

    init?(name: String, time1: NSDate, time2: NSDate, time3: NSDate, time4: NSDate, time5: NSDate) {
        self.name = name
        self.time1 = time1
        self.time2 = time2
        self.time3 = time3
        self.time4 = time4
        self.time5 = time5

        if name.isEmpty {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Inside of my table view controller I am trying to create the sample data.

```
import UIKit

class MedicineTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    //MARK Properties
    var data = [Data]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func loadSampleData() {
        let data1 = Data(name: "Example", time1: NSDate(dateString: "08:00 a"), time2: NSDate(dateString: "10:00 a"), time3: NSDate(dateString: "02:00 p"), time4: NSDate(dateString: "06:00 p"), time5: NSDate(dateString: "10:00 p"))

        Data += [data1]
    }
```

So first I started by trying to declare the times that I am storing just as integers in the format "HH:MM" but then this caused Xcode to store my values just as integers, I then did some research online and found the `NSDate` (dateString) and thought I can just define my times like that but this is also returning an error

> "Cannot find an initializer for type 'NSDate' that accepts an argument list of type '(dateString: String)'"

Can someone help explain to me whats going wrong here am I just formatting the `NSDate` incorrectly or is there an underlying problem with my code?

Comment: A date is a point in time. You can't store only time (hour and minute). You need to specify a date also (MM/dd/yyyy) and create a convenience initializer to be able to input your date as string.

Comment: This line doesn't make sense `Data += [data1]` You are trying to add a new element to the type here. Instead, you should use `data.append(data1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is best done with an NSDateFormatter.
You should create a date formatter then use the `datefromString` method to create your NSDate. I'm unaware of an `NSDate(dateString: "<some string")` initializer. It's possible if you saw this in some sample code that someone had created an extension on NSDate for this.
Something like this should work to get your time values:

```
var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
let time1 = dateFormatter.dateFromString("August 6, 2015")
```

The you can create your Data object.

Also, this line doesn't make sense `Data += [data1]` You are trying to add a new element to the type here. Instead, you should use `data.append(data1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line:

```
var data = [Data]()
```

into this line:

```
var data = [NSDate]()
```

and delete the `name` string, I am not sure you can store string & NSDate in it.
Tell me your result

Comment: well the Data array has already been declared in the first instance and the format each entry has to include which is 4 dates and 1 string. When I follow your instructions the error remains.